# How to redirect the output of an invoked program to a file?

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg, io-redirection

I've got some PHP code that, among other things, uses `system()` to call ffmpeg to encode a video.  When I run this from a command line, I can redirect the output of the PHP script to a file in the usual way -- `php mycode.php > mycode.log` -- and I get not only whatever print statements I call in PHP, but also the stuff produced by ffmpeg, which I want.  All's well.

Now, however, I want to launch the PHP script in the background via a web page: I do some stuff on my site that causes this to run:

```
$the_command = "/bin/php $php_file_name > $log_file_name &";
$the_result = system($the_command, $retval);
```

This successfully runs my script in a background PHP process, and my videos are still getting encoded by ffmpeg.  However, the only thing I'm getting in my redirected log file are the print statements in the script -- the output of the ffmpeg invocations are getting sent off to the ether somewhere.  Is there any way I can get these saved in the log file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$the_command = "/bin/php $php_file_name > $log_file_name 2>&1";
```

Comment: Yup -- that does it.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO - because the ffmpeg writes it's messages to `stderr`. So, try something like:

```
$res = shell_exec("ffmpeg your_args >/tmp/log 2>&1 &");
```

this should redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file.